# Firebase upload issue

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When I want to conduct Firebase database upload I got an error:

```
UploadImagesComponent.html:38 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_firebase_app__.storage is not a function
at UploadImagesService.webpackJsonp.505.UploadImagesService.uploadImagesToFirebase (upload-images.service.ts:35)
at UploadImagesComponent.webpackJsonp.510.UploadImagesComponent.uploadImagesToFirebase (upload-images.component.ts:28)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (UploadImagesComponent.html:38)
at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12022)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13486)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13074)
at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8615)
at core.es5.js:9226
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.es5.js:2651)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:367)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:366)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:420)
```

Does anybody have a clue what is going on?

Comment: can you show how you import and call the firebase storage?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"